# Convert YUV image to single byte array

Tags: android, image, image-processing, android-camerax

I am using `CameraX` to obtain frames from the camera for further analysis. The callback returns `ImageProxy` object that contains 3 planes of YUV_420_888 image. Now, I want to pass this image to 3rd party library for further processing. The function there accepts one dimensional byte array with "raw image data" - as documentation says. I don't understand how can I convert those 3 arrays (Y, U, V) into one byte array.

I have tried to convert it into `Bitmap` and then to byte array but the library returns that input is invalid. I have also tried to take only one channel from YUV and pass it to the library and it worked but the results were poor because (as I am guessing) one channel didn't carry enough information for the algorithms.

How can I merge Y, U and V channels into one byte array?

Comment: Have you tried just concatenating the individual Y, U, and V arrays, in that order? (Total size should end up being `w * h * 3 / 2`).

Comment: @greeble31 Unfortunately, when I do that I get `INVALID_PARAMETER` from the library.

Comment: Any byte array of size `w * h * 3 / 2` is a valid YUV 4:2:0 image; it doesn't matter what the contents are. You probably need to understand your library's input specification better. Please provide more information on that. How do you know that it supports YUV? We may also be able to draw conclusions from the "poor results" you mentioned, if you want to post a screenshot.